# How to apply a class to the result of a jQuery ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have tried finding an answer to this, but no success.

I have the following code:

```
jQuery("#categories_parent_id").change(function() {
            id = jQuery("#categories_parent_id").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'index.php?option=com_jomdirectory&task=getselect&format=raw',
                dataType: "html",
                data: "id=" + id,
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#selectlist').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

The ajax result select should have classes "form-control" and "chosen-select", and I tried adding them in the ajax view itself, but it does not style.

How would I go about adding the classes in question to the specific select after the ajax result?

Thanks

J

Comment: That's really looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because what you want i guess is to initialize choosen plugin on these elements. Adding class `chosen-select` won't do it, call plugin on new added elements instead

Comment: @A.Wolff It is because of guys like you that Stack Overflow should have "Buy this guy a beer" function.  Because you deserve a beer.

Answer (score 1):

Later edit, as @A.Wolff mentions you need to call the plugin on the newly added select element.

```
success: function(data) {
    jQuery('#selectlist').html(data).find('select').chosen();
}
```

---

Using [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
success: function(data) {
    jQuery('#selectlist').html(data).addClass("form-control chosen-select");
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex - this applies the style to the #selectlist div (which is the container for the select) and not to the select itself.

Comment: ok, so the select is inside the ajax response itself, see the answer from @Mohamed-Yousef it should work just fine, you just find the select element inside the `data` and `addClass`

Comment: does the `select` have an id or class you can reference?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `.find()` to find an element inside html data and then `addClass()` to it

```
jQuery('#selectlist').html(data).find('select').addClass('form-control chosen-select');
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed-Yousef, this does add the class, but the styling remains default.

Comment: @Jacques You asked wrong question... Initialize choosen plugin instead `jQuery('#selectlist').html(data).find('select').chosen()`